# fixed size map while keeping popular stuff only

Tags: c++, unordered-map

If I want to have a fixed size cache which only stores popular stuff, what should I try? I don't want to invent the wheel. Fixing the size of the map is easy,

```
static const int max_size = 100;
std::map<key_t, value_t> cache_map_t;
cache_map_t::const_iterator it = m_table.find( key );
if ( it != m_table.end() && m_table.size() == max_size ) { 
   // handle error, throw exception...
} else {
   m_table.insert( it, std::make_pair(key,value) );
}
```

and to find unpopular things, I can keep inserting till the max_size is reached, while having a "visit counter" which stores how many time each element is accessed. Once the max_size is reached, I can do one pass over the corresponding counters and delete the element with the lowest visit count. But this second part is not very efficient and wonder if there is any better solution.

Comment: Maybe you want to google for LRU cache.

Comment: Better to keep a secondary data structor like a list: whenever you access an item, move it to the head of the list. Whenever you hit max size, remove an item from the tail of the list. Both are O(1). Your map's "value" would point to its corresponding item in the list.